# How to Make MySQL join with same values in another table

Tags: php, mysql, join, count

I've got this table named `team_member`

```
memberid | teamid | groupid | ....
  123        12        45
  113        15        46
  ...       ....      ....
```

And then this table `members`

```
id | name | ipaddress | ...
123   Amy    8.45.1.23
113  Mark   12.4.41.124
...  ....   ..........
```

What I want is to make a list of members who has same ipaddress but they have 2 teams in the same groupid. Is It possible?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Your question is unclear.  What has two teams, the member or the ipaddress (or even the group)?

Comment: Table definitions and sample data are most welcome in the form of valid `CREATE TABLE ...` and `INSERT INTO ...` statements; makes it much easier to fiddle with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below query will return a list of IP addresses used by more than one distinct `id`. By using `GROUP BY` on the `ipaddress,groupid` we can limit the results to rows that share a groupid.

```
SELECT 
  ipaddress, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT id), groupid 
FROM
  member
JOIN 
  team_member
ON
  team_member.memberid = member.id
GROUP BY 
  ipaddress, groupid
HAVING 
  COUNT(DISTINCT id) > 1
ORDER BY 
  COUNT(DISTINCT id) DESC
```

You can see the query working here on some test data.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eced69/8/0

Comment: I already resolved this with a multiple PHP while loops who searched first the same ip addresses, then their teams in each group. But your query worked like a charm. Thanks ;)